# dbt found two resources with the same name

Tags: dbt

I'm hitting a strange error in dbt

I am using the following package to enable external tables in bigquery.

```
packages:
  - package: dbt-labs/dbt_external_tables
    version: 0.8.0
```

`$ dbt run-operation stage_external_sources`

> An error occurred in the dbt Server. Please contact support if this issue persists.
>
> RPC server failed to compile project, call the "status" method for compile status: Compilation Error
>
> dbt found two resources with the name
>
> "dbt_user_test_ext". Since these resources have the same name, dbt will be unable to find the correct resource when source("dbt_user", "test_ext") is used.  To fix this change the name of one of these resources:
>
> - source.dbt_user.test_ext (models/sources.yml)
> - source.dbt_user.test_ext (models/sources.yml) Code: 10011

models/sources.yml looks something like this:

```
sources:
  - name: "{{ target.schema }}"
    tables:
      - name: test_ext
        external:
          location: "gs://test-bucket/test_ext.csv"
          options:
            format: csv
            skip_leading_rows: 1
```

Seems to only happen the after the first time I run the command.

Question: what am I doing wrong, and/or how to fix?